# why could not ping gateway 192.168.31.1 in fedora 32

Tags: networking

my current ip is 192.168.31.77, but now I could not ping the gateway 192.168.31.1, this is my network using `ifconfig`:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv network-scripts]$ ifconfig
br0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.78  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        ether 06:b2:78:35:2c:73  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1  bytes 54 (54.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 2c:f0:5d:2c:6e:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xa1200000-a1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 21641  bytes 10131426 (9.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21641  bytes 10131426 (9.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:39:c6:9f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 306  bytes 29011 (28.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1275  bytes 349679 (341.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe68:f8d9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:68:f8:d9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18802  bytes 1759871 (1.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21395  bytes 2447455 (2.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.31.77  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::2ac2:c907:fd23:c4d8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 74:d8:3e:76:46:98  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 961736  bytes 1143507635 (1.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 373606  bytes 53955089 (51.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and this is the `arp -a` output:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv network-scripts]$ arp -a
? (192.168.31.29) at <incomplete> on br0
_gateway (192.168.31.1) at 50:d2:f5:7c:4a:60 [ether] on wlo1
? (192.168.31.30) at <incomplete> on br0
_gateway (192.168.31.1) at <incomplete> on br0
```

why could not ping the gateway address?

Comment: What interface is connected to your bridge `br0`?

Comment: Did you make sure the default gateway actually answers to ICMP pings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both `br0` and `wl01` share the same network (`192.168.31.7/24`), where the gateway is.

Assigning a different network to `wl01` will solve it.

You could also try to make a explicit route to `192.168.31.1` over the right device or add `wl01` to the bridge.

Comment: If `wlo1` is the physical interface it shouldn't have any IP address at all